# How to see all the annotations a class has in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

Suppose I have a class

```
@SessionScoped
class MyService implements Serializable{
    ....
}
```

It (probably) also has the annotations @Default @Any.

How can I see all the annotations this class has?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mixing Annotations and Qualifiers. Annotation is just a java language marker, that you have to explicitly add to your class by inserting a piece of text - `@MyAnnotationName` to you java source file. At runtime, you can only determine, whether a particular class or method had been annotated(if the annotation persists into class file). No one can add additional annotations to your class once it was compiled.
The `@Default` and `@Any` are CDI qualifier annotations. During deployment of your app(or initialization of the CDI container), the CDI manager will inspect all eligible classes and turn them into CDI Beans. It will scan the CDI annotations present on your class e.g. `@SessionScoped` and register an appropriate qualifier on the given bean. It can also add other qualifiers to your bean, even if you did not define them explicitly in your java code - like the above-mentioned `Default` and `Any`  This info however, is not stored in `.class` file, it is a runtime information related to a particular Bean instance or Bean definition, contained within CDI manager.
So back to your question. If you want to get all CDI qualifiers of some Bean or Bean class, you need to query bean manager not the class. The following should work(although I did not test it):

`CDI.current().getBeanManager().getBeans(MyService.class).iterator().next().getQualifiers()`

Happy hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Annotation[] annotations = MyService.class.getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

For more details, check the [`AnnotatedElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html) documentation.

Comment: I tried this, but than I only see SessionScoped, not Default for example.